# Why does my washer overflow the standpipe?

Tags: plumbing

It is a 2 inch ABS pipe with a trap and vent directly connected.  It has been snaked and the vent and drain are both declared "open". Still when the washer empties it can discharge about 1/2 of the water in the tub (when on a full load) and then the standpipe overflows.  After the initial discharge it takes much longer to gradually empty the remaining water by starting and stopping the draining process.

I believe there is a partial clog beyond the "Y" where the washer drain intersects. However the plumber that snaked it says it is clear and the washer "just puts out too much water."  (I had the washer at another house with no issues ever.)

I have no drain issues with any other sinks, tubs, showers etc.

Comment: does the washer hose has space in the standpipe, or is it a tight connection. It needs air to properly discharge. Also where is the vent connected, before or after the trap

Comment: The washer hose is not tight in the standpipe. (Washer hose is 1" diameter emptying into a 2" pipe)  The vent rises above the Y the standpipe trap empties into.

Comment: Do you have a cleanout pipe in the ground next to the house on the side that the sewer emerges from? Our house has a "double cleanout" in the front yard about 3 ft from the foundation. The outer cleanout (closer to the street) leads under the house; the inner cleanout (closer to the house) leads to the street. If a blockage is under the yard, then running water from a hose down the inner cleanout will cause water to rise in the cleanout. In the blockage is under the house, then running water into the inner yard cleanout will not cause water to rise in the cleanout.

Comment: How did the 2nd plumbing company diagnose the location of the partial clog?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> it can discharge about 1/2 of the water in the tub

This is a great deal of water for a 2" drain.  I won't bore you with the math, but it means the clog is much further down the pipe, possibly 20 or 50 feet down.  The sinks, tubs, and showers don't put out nearly this much water, so if you have a slow sewer line from the street to the house, running your washer is the only way you'd know about it.

The plumber who says your washer makes too much water doesn't need to be involved anymore.  Forget about that one.

It's time to hire a sewer cleaning company to find out if your line to the street is working.

Comment: "washer makes too much water" lol wut?

Answer (score 3):

The clog is *definitely* farther down than the incompetent, lazy plumber ran his snake. He just didn't want to go to the truck to get the longer snake (or drive back to the shop to pick it up).

Either hire a different plumber to do a full job of snaking your drains, or simply go to your local tool rental store and rent a power snake with the appropriate sized head on it and do it yourself.

Last time I had to do this, I had a clog in my main drain *after* the plumbing had left the house - it was in the run to the city sewer line. I had frequent clogs in the toilet and the tub would drain slowly, but everything else worked just fine.

I rented the power auger, opened the clean out in the garage and ran about 50' of the snake down the line. IIRC, it cost about $50 to rent the auger for 1/2 day (4 hours). It took about 30 minutes to get home from the store, about 1-1/2 - 2 hours to run the snake through the pipe 2 or 3 times, then a return run. I'm sure prices have gone up since then, and, of course, they'll vary depending on where you live. I provide a price just to give you an idea of the difference between DIY and hiring the plumber.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of lint and grease can reduce the effective diameter of the pipe enough to cause it to drain slowly or back up.  Snaking it with a typical conical screw snake won't help much, as that punches a hole in the center, but doesn't restore the full flow of the pipe.  You need to ensure that the pipe has no clogs and is clean.

Some of the solutions that I've seen are to use a drain bladder and pressurize the pipe  in the hope of making the flow faster, using the 'grease cutter' jaws (or mini-chains) on the power snake, or using a drain cleaning brush attached to a flexible coupling.  There are also water jetters, and potentially drain cleaning pigs.   Or you could open a cleanout below, thread a rope down there, and pull a tennis ball through.

You can also try enzymatic cleaners or full on chemical cleaners.

Comment: Thank you all for your input.  I did get a better plumbing company out and they found a partial clog in the main line to the street.  Cleaned it out and all is well now.  The first company also agreed to refund  me because they did not correct the problem.

Comment: How did the 2nd plumbing comany diagnose the location of the blockage?

Comment: They ran a camera down the cleanout.  Said it looked like a buildup of those flushable wipes.  I just rehabbed the house and rented it .  Of course the day before the tenants were moving in, the issue manifested itself.  Done now and all is well.